# general local to global principle

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

Consider the Diophantine equation $f(x)=0$, where x is a vector of integers and $f: \mathbb Z^n \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ is a polynomial function. Is the following statement true?

The structure of the set of solutions to $f(x)=0$ is uniquely determined by the number of solutions to $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod{p^i}$ for each prime $p$ and $i>0$.

If it is unknown whether the statement is true, please explain what we know about the statement.

In particular, do we know that this is true for elliptic curves or is it necessary to prove the Birch Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture to know this?

Comment: My question was inspired by the Birch Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture.

Comment: @mvw, good catch. I made a correction.

Comment: What does the "structure" of the set of solutions mean to you? Merely counting solutions modulo prime powers won't allow you to distinguish between $f(x,y)=x$, $f(x,y)=y$, $f(x+y)=x+y$, or $f(x,y)=0$ (in each case the number of solutions is always $\aleph_0$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, in the case of the Birch Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture, that would be the rank of the elliptic curve. But I left the word "structure" as a soft terminology. That's why I made this a soft question.